# Link for launching and adding to Evernote app

Tags: android, html, ios, uri, evernote

I want to add a button to my site so that when a user clicks it, it opens a new note on the Evernote app and saves a specific message.

I've looked everywhere for this but didn't find any info about it.

Is this possible?

---

Edit:

I'm sorry the question isn't very specific but I'm not really sure on where to start.

So, what I was asking was is there was a way to create a link with an href that would open in the Evernote app. So:

- Is it possible to add an href that will open on the Whatsapp app? (I've seen that something like **evernote://** should do it, but how's the syntax of this and does this work in both iOS and Android?)
- Is there code in Javascript that would do the requested? (opening the Evernote app with a text that I would choose).

Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: You've tagged this post as both Android and iOS so I'm not sure which platform you want sample code for. But this may help you: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php

Comment: For both. Is the code different? So I guess you can't do this in plain HTML.